# php string to associative array

Tags: php, string, associative-array

I'm trying to store a set of data in a TEXT field in my MySQL database. The data to store are as follow (data format is not fixed yet):

```
[location1] => (lat,lon,zoom)
[location2] => (lat,lon,zoom)
[location3] => (lat,lon,zoom)
etc...
```

In the end all these data will be one single string. How should I write/format this string so that I can then use it in PHP as a regular associative array?

Comment: http://php.net/serialize or http://php.net/json_encode

Comment: Storing formatted data in a database negates the purpose of having the database in the first place. That reduces it to just being a very 'expensive' file storage medium. Create a table that contains `location, lat, lon, zoom` fields and store each datum in its assigned field.

Comment: Alright but isn't it a problem if a table ends up with millions of rows?

Comment: Well storing the values in a gigantic text field isn't going to alleviate the problem of storing a million rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you save them in an individual table with this scheme:

`Foreign key | Location (text) | lat (double) | lon (double) | zoom (double)`

Comment: I could do that but I would prefer not create another table. Plus, I'm interested in the solution to this problem ^^